# Changing audio stream from physical input

Tags: c++, windows, audio

I wondering about method to change voice from microphone on Windows on as low level as possible. So other applications will take changed voice on their inputs.

Some programs takes original stream, pipes it on virtual microphone, change here, and then forwards to an application.

I am looking for a method to affect on original audio stream. Looks like it is requires writing custom C++ audio driver for specific microphone. Is there any guideline for this? Maybe i can modify default driver for my purposes? Or maybe there is an easier method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of change is considered "Digital Signal Processing" or DSP, and in the Windows architecture that's the job of [Audio Processing Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/windows-audio-processing-objects) or APO's.

Microsoft indeed provides a base class, `CBaseAudioProcessingObject`. And there's even a "swap" sample which swaps the right and left channels.

Comment: Thanks, seems it is that i was looking for, but as i can see, this solution works on user level. Is there any way to manipulate with raw input from kernel level?

Comment: @Bacsick: Why would you even want that? Writing kernel-mode code is a major extra headache. Just the signing alone is reason enough to avoid it. And it's quite easy to blue-screen your PC with a kernel driver.

Comment: i am thinking about microphone noising as protection from any kind of eavesdropping. Noising at user level looks not really better than simply switch device off on windows settings.